# Django ORM appending Table Name when accessing table

Tags: python, django

I am  new to Django and I just finished my first app. Now, I want to deploy it. As this app is not stable, I deployed it with the lightweight Python `runserver` command on the server.

I took a dump of my database and generated the same database with this dump on the server. Now the problem is, when I run the application, the Django ORM accesses the database with `[dbname].[tablename]` for example `hubstaff.logentry_project`. `hubstaff` is the name of the database on the server, `logentry` is the app name, and `logentry_project` is the table name.

The database contains tables without the [database] prefix (only `logentry_project`) so it gives an error `(1146, "Table 'hubstaff.LogEntry_project' doesn't exist")`

Here is my settings.py for DATABASE:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.path.join('hubstaff'),
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'haha',
        'HOST':'localhost'

    }
}
```

The following is the MySQL dump:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `logentry_project`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logentry_project` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` date NOT NULL,
  `endDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourceOfProject` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `paymentType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectPaymentAmount` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `sourceName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `projectSeverity` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `hubstaffName` varchar(30),
  `hoursToWork` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `LogEntry_project_name_096d434e_uniq` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The following is the stack trace of error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://104.248.12.78:8000/admin/projects/

Django Version: 2.1.1
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['LogEntry',
 'Administration',
 'Accounts',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /root/django/templates/base.html, error at line 25
   1146
   15 :     <!-- Jquery Data Tabels -->
   16 :     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
   17 :     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   18 : 
   19 : 
   20 :     <!--BootStrap-->
   21 : 
   22 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   23 :     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   24 :     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   25 :     <lin k rel="stylesheet" hr ef="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
   26 : 
   27 : 
   28 :     <!-- Date Picker CSS -->
   29 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'LogEntry/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css' %}>
   30 :     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   31 : 
   32 :     <!-- Date Picker JS -->
   33 :     <script src={% static 'LogEntry/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' %}  ></script>
   34 : 
   35 : 


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  250.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  50.         raise errorvalue

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  247.             res = self._query(query)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  412.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  375.         db.query(q)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  276.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1146, "Table 'hubstaff.LogEntry_project' doesn't exist")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  109.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/django/Administration/views.py" in get
  281.      return render(request,'Administration/projects.html' , {'emp_pr':emp_pr})

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  71.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  250.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  50.         raise errorvalue

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  247.             res = self._query(query)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  412.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  375.         db.query(q)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  276.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/projects/
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'hubstaff.LogEntry_project' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Are you sure about the table name is 'logentry_project' and that really exists?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dumping SQL, its better to do the [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/) to create tables. Also you can [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) from local machine(as fixtures) and [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) it in your production server. For example:

#### Migration:

```
python manage.py migrate # will generate tables
```

*Before Migrate Command, please make sure to have migrations file beforehand. You can create the migration files using `python manage.py makemigrations`. Also please commit those migrations files if you are using version controlling.*

#### Dump Data(in Local Machine):

```
python manage.py dumpdata db.json
```

#### Load Data(In prod):

```
python manage.py loaddata db.json
```

[Here](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata) is a good tutorial on using dumpdata and loaddata in more details.